# how to use sed to get string between specific character and space?

Tags: sed

In below string I want the digits between `-` and space

```
RXOTG-196 HK6500A 0
```

The result i want is 196
How can i do it using sed?
The number of digits is not necessarily 3 , sometimes it is 2 or 1 digit.

Comment: how if i the above input `RXOTG-196 HK6500A 0`  is just one line among multiline input, I want just the 169 and not other extra lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern works in my sed:

```
sed -e 's_^[^-]*-\([^ ]*\).*$_\1_'
```

Comment: Funny to add `$` anchor after `.*` =)

Comment: Less is best :D

Comment: What would happen if there was a `-` before the `-` followed by a number followed by a space?

Comment: Then the second hyphen would be included in the output, e.g. `-196`.  If you want to soak up any number of hyphens at that point in the pattern, use a plus sign: `-+`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/-([0-9]+) /\n\1\n/;/^[0-9]+\n/P;D' file
```

Surround the required string by newlines and only print lines that match numbers followed by a newline. This will print all matches on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'RXOTG-196 HK6500A 0' | sed -E 's/.*[A-Z]-([0-9]+).*/\1/' 
196
```